# What's the best application server applicable for Web Applications?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, glassfish, application-server, apache-tomee

What would be best application server applicable for web application purpose? I have been working with Glassfish 3.1 and little bit with Tomcat and TomEE. This far I must say that the winner from those three servers is absolutely Glassfish because almost everything works smoothly in it. With TomEE I'm getting lots of errors even from basic things like setting up JSF in Eclipse and it is very time consuming to fix all those problems, however it is rewarding in the way that you learn how to fix the problems.

What are your opinions about this?

Comment: See [dont-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can lead to very opinion-based answers, so it's hard to give a good answer.

However, based on my experience JBoss is one of the most fully-featured, if not the most fully-featured of all Java EE containers. It has excellent integration with Eclipse. There is also an excellent in-container test framework you can use to run your tests in the JBoss container itself called Arquillian which I've found to be excellent (technically though Arquillian can work with several different containers).

I think you need to consider your needs. JBoss is the most complete, but also one of the heaviest containers. If you don't intend on using all Java EE features you may be able to go with something lighter light Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have being doing some researches and it seem that from security point of view Tomcat is very restricted and as far as I know it is supported with JSP and Servlets, but you can add other technology supports to it when you add their JAR's for example JSF, EJB and others. You answer helped me, thank you :)